# Rails Active Admin unpermitted parameter

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, activeadmin

I have some problem/issues with active admin on rails, specifically unpermitted params error:

[existing active admin parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYIsj.png)

here is the existing active admin parameter

[model associated with the main model im working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vitcr.png)

As per active admin documentation I should be doin right, as the other attributes for dispatch_information model is being accepted by rails and I was able to read and write with out any issues. Just with this recently added attribute "custom_attorney". Associations already set. and with out declaring an attr_accessor on model file it says this error

[No method error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le5sW.png)

as it seems it cannot read or detect the column that I added for dispatch_information model, while in my console its already there.

When I add it with attr_accessor "while it should not, just to proceed on the form page" then I fill in the attributes need, im getting weird stuff in my console

[Console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnzcR.png)

as you can see it seems it being added inside efile_order hash instead of dispatch_information_attribute hash, and at the bottom part of the image you can see it says unpermitted parameters, even I added it inside the correct attribute block, we can also notice that the other attributes pf dispatch_information works really fine, just this recently added custom_attorney attribute. I already did everything like migration and other stuff.

[Form Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id6Pd.png)

here is my form where we can see that input is on the same block where dispatch_defendant and dispatch_plaintiff is included and those two attribute works fine as well.

I really dont know what I missed here. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `custom_attorney` should be nested under `dispatch_information_attributes` you have it in the wrong place so it's unpermitted.

The correct way to do that is to add a block for those attributes and nest them.

```
- f.simple_fields_for :dispatch_information do |d|
  - d.input :custom_attorney, :input_html => { id: 'new-attorney' }
```

It may be a good idea to provide an object for `dispatch_information` if you care for existing data. Assuming your `ivar` is named `@e_filling_order` then you should have the following.

```
- f.simple_fields_for :dispatch_information, @e_filling_order.dispatch_information || @e_filling_order.build_dispatch_information do |d|
```

Comment: Actually on my 1st screenshot it was already nested under dispatch_information_attributes and Im using the existing form which has the other attributes of dispatch_information model in which everything works well and was able to save a value. So I really dont know what I am doing wrong

Comment: I agree to this, was able to figure it out, on the existing code, previous programmer have it this way, f.input :custom_attorney, :input_html => {name: 'efiling_order[dispatch_information_attributes][custom_attorney]'}

Comment: So I definitely agree with Christos, thank you sir, I was able to focus on the form itself rather than other things on rails and was able to noticed it. kudos. :)